# std::sort crashes with strict weak ordering - comparing with garbage values

Tags: c++

I have written a compare-function that should compare two possible move options for a player in a game that works like Chess. Each Move contains a Figure that should do the move and a Point, where it will move. The Points are already checked, so all of them are valid moves. When I try to sort a list containing all of the moves currently available using strict weak ordering and the std::sort function, I get a SIGSEG after my compare function got confrontet with some garbage Figure Pointer in one Move.

I already tried to figure out where the garbage pointer came from, but ony found, that the std::sort function somehow put it in the mix of all the other moves. The same seg fault occurs when i try to sort with std::stable_sort. I also thougt about stack issues due to the fact, that I had some before, but this isn't the case either.

```
bool cmpWhite(White_Move m1, White_Move m2) {

    if (m1.f == nullptr) {
        return true;
    } else if (m2.f == nullptr) {
        return true;
    }

    int sum1 = 0;
    double avg1 = 0;
    Figure *f1 = m1.f;
    Point origin1 = f1->getCoordinatesAsPoint();
    int sum2 = 0;
    double avg2 = 0;
    Figure *f2 = m2.f;
    Point origin2 = f2->getCoordinatesAsPoint();

    Point p;

    movePiece(field_pub, f1, m1.p);
    std::vector<Point> moves = black_king->getAllNewPossiblePositions();
    for (int i = 0; i < moves.size(); i++) {
        p = moves[i];
        if (!black_king->isPositionBlocked(field_pub, p.x, p.y)) {
            sum1++;
            // avg1 += sqrt((p.x - target_pub.x) * (p.x - target_pub.x) + (p.y - target_pub.y) * (p.y - target_pub.y));
        }
    }
    p = black_king->getCoordinatesAsPoint();
    if (!black_king->isPositionBlocked(field_pub, p.x, p.y)) {
        sum1++;
    }
    // avg1 = (double)sum1;
    movePiece(field_pub, f1, origin1);

    movePiece(field_pub, f2, m2.p);
    moves = black_king->getAllNewPossiblePositions();
    for (int i = 0; i < moves.size(); i++) {
        p = moves[i];
        if (!black_king->isPositionBlocked(field_pub, p.x, p.y)) {
            sum2++;
            // avg2 += sqrt((p.x - target_pub.x) * (p.x - target_pub.x) + (p.y - target_pub.y) * (p.y - target_pub.y));
        }
    }
    p = black_king->getCoordinatesAsPoint();
    if (!black_king->isPositionBlocked(field_pub, p.x, p.y)) {
        sum2++;
    }
    // avg2 = (double)sum2;
    movePiece(field_pub, f2, origin2);
    std::cout << "cmp: " << sum1 << " " << sum2 << std::endl;
    return sum1 < sum2;
}
```

```
std::vector<White_Move> sortBestMovesForWhite(Figure **figures, int size, King *bKing, int **field, Point target) {
    target_pub = target;
    field_pub = new int *[FIELD_WIDTH];
    for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++) {
        field_pub[x] = new int[FIELD_HEIGHT];
        for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++) {
            field_pub[x][y] = field[x][y];
        }
    }
    black_king = bKing;
    std::vector<White_Move> moves;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Figure *f = figures[i];
        std::vector<Point> m_point = f->getAllNewPossiblePositions();
        for (int j = 0; j < m_point.size(); j++) {
            if (!f->isPositionBlocked(field, m_point.at(j).x, m_point.at(j).y)) {
                White_Move move = {f, m_point.at(j)};
                moves.push_back(move);
            }
        }
    }
    // std::stable_sort(moves.begin(), moves.end(), cmpWhite);
    std::sort(moves.begin(), moves.end(), cmpWhite);
    for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++) {
        delete[] field_pub[x];
    }
    delete[] field_pub;
    return moves;
}
```

Comment: The code shown suggests the type `White_Move` may be managing raw pointers.  Have you implemented the [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)?

Comment: White_Move ist just a struct containing a raw Figure Pointer f and a Point p

Comment: Also, the other methods that will get called are tested and work like expected.

Answer (score 2):

One of your `return true` at the start of your compare function should be `return false`. The comparator for `std::sort` must meet the conditions specified here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare. If this is not the case `std::sort` will have undefined behaviour.

The correct implementation should look something like:

```
bool cmpWhite(White_Move m1, White_Move m2) {

    if (m1.f == nullptr) {
        return m2.f != nullptr;
    }
    if (m2.f == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I've already tried that. If I check for nullptr, the sort algorithm will give me cmp function some other random adress with no valid value so the check is actually kind of obsolete. Also, the problem only occurs after about 100 std::sort function calls.